# How to link Login.js to /login

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginning in ReactJS and I don't found how to make that my Login.js is used when I go on http://0.0.0.0:3000/login instead of load App.js

Comment: Read up on routing in reactJS

Comment: Yeah React Router might help you, but since you're just starting out then go with dealwaps suggestion and read up on basic routing. You can read more here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Yep I read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ReactJS Router, there is a tutorial on how to use it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_router.htm).